# How to SELECT * FROM table WHERE month AND year in SQLite database by rawQuery(query, args)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, strftime

I was trying to select all the columns in the table where the "month" and "year" are the same.
The method rawQuery(query,args) receive an array of string[] with the a query that replaces the camps with  "?".

This was some of my attempts:

```
"SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m', EXPENSE_DATE)=" + month + " AND strftime('%y',EXPENSE_DATE) =" + year;
```

and

```
"SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%Y/%m', 'EXPENSE_DATE')  =" + year + "/" + month;
```

and the last with the "?" replacing the args with the method in question:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month)};

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE expense_date >='?-?-01' AND expense_date <='?-?-31'", selectionArgs);
```

In the end after the problem appear again, i discovered that the problem was that the Object of the view was giving one DATE and the system was giving another format.

Basically i have a CALENDARVIEW that was giving me the data format of ("00-0-00") and if the variable was null the program would get the system date which was giving me the date format ("00-00-00")

The code to fill the null date was this:

```
//Get the default TIMEZONE
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//Set the format date
simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

and the CALENDARVIEW was this:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    date = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;//the Time will be blanck

            }
        });
```

The solution was:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // the date was being save as 00-0-00 instead of 00-00-00
        if (month >10) {
            date = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;//the Time will be blanck
        }else {
            date = year + "-0" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;//the Time will be blanck
        }
    

  }
});
```

and for the database in android just worked with strf:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month)};
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE "+
             "strftime('%Y', EXPENSE_DATE) = ? AND strftime('%m', EXPENSE_DATE) + 0 = ? + 0"; 
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

THAT'S IT THANKS FOR THE HELP GUYS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `?` placeholders in the sql statement and pass the parameters as an array in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`.
This is the recommended and safe way to do it.

I assume that the variables `year` and `month` are integers, this is why you use `String.valueOf()` to convert them to strings inside the string array.
I also assume that the column `EXPENSES` has the correct format `YYYY-MM-DD` so that `strftime()` will succeed to extract the year and the month.

The problem is that when you extract the month with `strftime()` it is returned as a string: a number left padded with a `0` if needed, say `05`.
But if the value of `month` that you pass is 1-digit integer, say `5`, the condition in the `WHERE` clause will become:

```
WHERE '05' = '5'
```

which returns `false`.
To overcome this problem you need an implicit conversion of the result of `strftime()` to an integer by adding `0`.
For the year, since the values are always 4 digits, there is no such problem, but remember to use the `'%Y'` format inside `strftime()`, which stands for 4-digit years and not `'%y'` which stands for 2-digit years.

So write your code like this:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month)};
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE "+
             "strftime('%Y', EXPENSE_DATE) = ? AND strftime('%m', EXPENSE_DATE) + 0 = ? + 0"; 
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: I tried with no success, the code doesn't show any error either. My date format is ('yyy-MM-dd');

Comment: @Matheus I missed a `+0` in my code. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is dangerous. This will open your app for a SQL injection attack. For a local database that only has one user, this probably isn't a big deal. But you should get in the habit of using bound parameters as in the second query.

The problem is that you can only use `?` as a place holder for the **entire** value, so your query should be:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE expense_date >= ? AND expense_date <= ?"
```

Now you will need to build a date object or a formatted string to pass as the arguments:

```
String begin = year + "-" + month + "-01";
String end = year + "-" + month + "-31";
```

Finally execute the query:

```
String selectionArgs = new String[]{begin, end};
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `BETWEEN` keyword here instead of two explicit inequality comparisions:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE expense_date BETWEN ? AND ?"
```